# How to disable overriding of cookies?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am new to web development. I am using asp.net web API and angular i am using token authentication when a user logged in i set the token in a cookie and send it with every request till now every thing is working fine but if the user duplicates tab in the same browser and logged in with two different account the cookie is set to the last logged in account so the token for the two accounts became the same. how can i separate between them

Comment: I don't believe you can do this. The cookie is requested by domain, not by browser window/tab. So every tab in the browser will have access to the cookies for your domain, and reading/writing to a cookie for one user account will always override the details of the other user account. Are you able to rethink your approach? Why do you need to be able to login two accounts at the same time?

Comment: You are right but how can i dsiable login with two accounts at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Include the currently logged-in user's username in a custom header on every page request. Then in every call from client to server, send back the username again in a custom header through angular (use an interceptor).

On the server side when a request comes in, compare the logged-in user's username in the session and the logged-in user's name according to the request header. If the request header doesn't match the session, then you know the user logged into a different account on a new tab. Return an error.

*Note:* If you do want to be able to open a new tab and not share cookies (good for QA), open the new tab in incognito mode or in a separate browser (i.e., if you use chrome, then use firefox).

Comment: On the server side i have  ActionFilterAttribute which intercepts every request to validate a token which have user id and etc.. and also a base controller that have current user object in the API. so you want me to create another Filter to check if the user id in the token equals user id send from Clint.!

Comment: I also if you mind try to have a functionality like Facebook where you can not open more than one account on the same browser but you can open them in different browsers

Comment: @MohamedAbbas, you don't want to validate the token from the client and the userid from the client. Validate the userid from the client against the userid stored in the server's session memory from when the user logged in.